# How to self describe a REST api with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I'm using `spring-mvc` to create servlets like:

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
   @GetMapping("/test")
   public MyRsp test(MyReq req) {
         //...
   }
}
```

Now if the user accesses the root of my app `localhost:8080/my-app`, it should show a list of `GET` and `POST` methods available. At best with possible input parameters, acceptable headers etc.

Question: is that possible with any spring framework, like `HATEOAS`?

I'd expect a framework to auto detect any `@RestController` and included methods.

Or would I have to create that overview page myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swagger 2** is an another option. read the following to know more about swagger and how to set it up.

[Setting Up Swagger 2 with a Spring REST API](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

You can also create swagger definition for your rest apis, which can be used by the clients to generate client classes.

Also the swagger ui can be used to test/invoke your APIs. swagger provides a user interface where you can input all the api inputs such as query params, path params, request body, headers.

[Sample Swagger UI](http://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet)

Answer (score 4):

You should must look into [this](http://swagger.io/)

To integrate it in spring you can refer [this](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

Swagger is one of the best framework to expose RESTful API's.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this project [Spring Restdocs](https://projects.spring.io/spring-restdocs/) ([github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs)), which allows you to generate ready to use REST documentation. It's officially maintained by Spring Team:

> The primary goal of this project is to make it easy to document
>   RESTful services by combining content that's been hand-written using
>   Asciidoctor with auto-generated examples produced with the Spring MVC
>   Test framework. The result is intended to be an easy-to-read user
>   guide, akin to [GitHub's API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) for example, rather than the
>   fully automated, dense API documentation produced by tools like
>   [Swagger](http://swagger.io/).

The other option is to use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/getting-started/), it supports bottom-up approach as well:

> A bottom-up approach where you have an existing REST API for which you
>   want to create a Swagger definition. Either you create the definition
>   manually (using the same Swagger Editor mentioned above), or if you
>   are using one of the supported frameworks (JAX-RS, node.js, etc), you
>   can get the Swagger definition generated automatically for you.

Some examples of swagger are mentioned here: [1](http://heidloff.net/article/usage-of-swagger-2-0-in-spring-boot-applications-to-document-apis/) [2](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But writing test for documentation purpose is not my intention. I'd be happy to just show an overview of available GET/POST methods, alongside with possible parameters and http headers.

Comment: you're welcome. In such case you can look for "Swagger" http://swagger.io/